# Solving Addition Rule other way

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I know the General Addition Rule for Two Events is

> $$P (A\cup B) = P (A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$$

I know the proof where ${R_1} = A\cap B, R_2 = A\cap B', R_3 = A'\cap B,$ and $R_4 = A'\cap B'.$ The $R_i$'s are a partition of a sample space S and they are disjoint.

However I was wondering if we can prove this by making use of the set equations:

$A\cup B =A\cup(A'\cap B) $(I know the RHS is disjoint) and
$B = (A\cap B)\cup(A'\cap B) $(where the RHS is disjoint).

How would one go proving the theorem using these set equations? Can someone please show me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\cup B =A\cup(A'\cap B)$ (the RHS is disjoint) implies $P(A\cup B) =P(A)+P(A'\cap B)$

$B = (A\cap B)\cup(A'\cap B)$ (the RHS is disjoint) implies $P(B)=P(A\cap B)+P(A'\cap B)$

Now substitute $P(A'\cap B)$ from the second equation into the first. Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Yes I wanted to know how would you use these two equations to solve this addion theorem. I was not to sure about the substitution though. Is this how you would solve it: $P(A'\cap B)=P(B)-P(A\cap B)$ then $P(A\cup B) =P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$
which is the final answer. This seems like a simple way to prove the General Addition Rule though.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.

Comment: :) Another thing: the comment must be at least 15 characters, so I needed to add something, which is what this sentence is for.