# How to prove the inclusion exclusion formula for probabilities on 2 events?

Tags: probability

How to prove the inclusion exclusion formula for probabilities on 2 events? That is: $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$ It seems quite obvious the result but I don't know how to go about proving it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Draw a Venn diagram first. It will suggest the proof....

Comment: I already did. Still doesn't seem to show me where to go. Maybe I'm just being bad.

Comment: Also see [Solving Addition Rule other way](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/658164/139123).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2917915/321264

Answer (score 0):

$A=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)$  and $B=(B\setminus A)\cup(A\cap B)\quad$ (disjoint unions).

Also $A\cup B=(A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap B)\cup(B\setminus A)$ (disjoint union). So 
$$P(A\cup B)= P(A)-P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B)+P(B)-P(A\cap B).$$

Comment: I did this and got. $P(A\setminus B)+P(B\setminus A)=P(A)+P(B)-2P(A\cap B)$ Not sure what else to do.

Comment: See my completed answer.

Comment: Is there an error in your answer?

Comment: I've corrected the wrong formula. Thanks for pointing it.