# Suppose $\textbf{P}(A)\geq 0.9$, $\textbf{P}(B)\geq 0.8$ and $\textbf{P}(A\cap B\cap C) = 0$. Show that $\textbf{P}(C) \leq 0.3$.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

So $\textbf{P}(A \cup B) = \textbf{P}(A) + \textbf{P}(B) - \textbf{P}(A \cap B)$, and we know $\textbf{P}(A\cup B)\leq 1$.

So $0.9 + 0.8 - 1 \leq \textbf{P}(A\cap B)$ which is $0.7 \leq \textbf{P}(A\cap B)$.

My professor did this:

$\textbf{P}((A\cap B)\cup C) = \textbf{P}(A\cap B) + \textbf{P}(C) - \textbf{P}(A\cap B\cap C)$

I have no idea where or how he got that equation above, but going further it solves the problem but I don't know how or why.

Answer (score 1):

Yust mark $D= A\cap B$ and use again 
$$ P(D\cup C) = P(D)+P(C)-P(D\cap C)$$

Comment: I'm asking HOW he got $P((A\cap B) \cup C)$. Not what it equals to.

Comment: YOU mean WHY he use that?

Comment: Yes, how and why?

Comment: I don't know what is in his head so YOU must ask HIM.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\P}{\textbf{P}}$That equation is [because](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131057/how-to-prove-the-inclusion-exclusion-formula-for-probabilities-on-2-events) $\P(E\cup C) = \P(E) + \P(C) - \P(E\cap C)$. Then set $E = A\cap B$.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. Thanks for being helpful unlike some people.

Comment: Nice! And no worries. :)

Comment: @Stuy I wrote exactly the same thing and you somehow understand this and you don't understand my answer. Very strange.

Comment: Any way, I suggest you to visit this: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour